# How can we use Postman collection in Nightwatch?

Tags: postman, nightwatch.js, postman-collection

We have a Postman collection. We want to verify data created from API in web. One way is we can integrate both in jenkins, but we want to perform all verification through nightwatch only. Is there any way to utilise Postman collection in Nightwatch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In terms of using postman ‘in’ Nightwatch, you wouldn’t be able to do this I believe and I wouldn’t recommend it if you could.

If what you are saying is you want to be able to make api calls from within Nightwatch, then that is certainly possible and I’d recommend trying something like axios

Comment: yes, thanks for the response
Now we are using xmlhttprequest to make api calls